# Which RAID is best for private use of NAS

Tags: raid, hard-drive, network-attached-storage

I want to buy the DS 920+ with (4x)6TB Seagate IronWolf NAS HDD.
I definitely want some reliability. I obviously don't want to lose any data which is stored on the NAS.

Which RAID would be the best?
I think RAID 1 (12 TB is enough of course) but what about RAID 5?
Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically it is a terrible idea to use RAID 5 on any HDD that is larger than 2 TB - your chance of a read error WHILE reconstructing is too high. RAID 6 is the only answer here. That is the case with nearline HDD - your end user level HDD have 10x the chance to fail than those.

And never be stupid enough to assume that RAID stops you from the need to have a backup. I had an 8 disk RAID 6 fail once - 2 HDD failed within minutes. You always need a backup separate from the RAID.

Answer (score -1):

Synology will handle the RAID and filesystem managements for you. They have a [nice tool](https://www.synology.com/en-global/support/RAID_calculator) and documentations.

If your NAS is your only backup and you don't need high performances, then RAID5 will give you more usable space than RAID1.

However, filesystems like BTRFS and ZFS are a better way to go. But again, Synology will take care of the technical things for you.